# FileSystemWatcher events called multiple times

Tags: c#, windows, triggers, console-application, filesystemwatcher

I have created a Console application to watch a specific folder by using **filesystemwatcher**.
when i make any changes or create or rename or delete in any of the file it will trigger a event.
but when i change the file 2 events are getting triggered.I need only one event should be triggered for that respective action....

Below are my code which triggering 2 events when i change the file

```
public static void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

                string myFilePath = e.FullPath;
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(myFilePath);
                if (ext == ".tmp" || ext == ".TMP" || ext == "")
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.WriteLine("A new file has been changed - " + e.Name + " " + "on" + " " + date + " File Changed", Console.ForegroundColor);
                    //  SendAttachmentMail("A File Has Been Changed - " + e.Name + "", date, "File Changed");
                    //File_Date = date;
                    //watcher.Dispose();



            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). What is also documented is that you are not guaranteed that all events will be delivered. Application must protect itself against either case.

> Common file system operations might raise more than one event. For
>   example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several
>   OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised.
>   Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple
>   operations, therefore raising multiple events. Likewise, some
>   applications (for example, antivirus software) might cause additional
>   file system events that are detected by FileSystemWatcher.

Also note that the above is Win32 behavior, FSW is just wrapping up the operating system feature into a nicer interface.